# Returning Autogenerated Column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create a new employee in the database and needs to use the Autogenerated EmployeeID.

Can't find the way the procedure needs to be written and use the autogenerated value in my c# code.

Please help me out
Thanks

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, there is no reason to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SCOPE_IDENTITY() function returns the most recently created Identity value in the current SQL execution scope, and is the recommended way to find the ID in a stored procedure that just did an INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(col1, col2) VALUES "abc", "xyz";

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

You can return the value from your stored procedure to you C# client either 1) as a dataset by using SELECT (as above), or, 2) as the RETURN value from you stored procedure, or 3) by passing it back through an OUTPUT parameter declared in you stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Like This :

```
using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();

        command.CommandText = @"
            INSERT Test (Name)
            VALUES (@TestName)
            ";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TestName", "SomeName");
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
        int id = command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

Comment: This is good too, except you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY.

Comment: You are right , thanks for correcting me :).. While @@IDENTITY is limited to the current session, it is not limited to the current scope.